# Adding dynamic value to a function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement a plugin:

```
$(".myTbl th:nth-child(1)").truncate({
        width: "200",
        after: "&hellip;",
        center: false,
        addtitle: true
});
```

Instead of using a fixed value for width, I have a script that calculates it dynamically and sets it into a a variable, but when I plug it in the code breaks. What am I missing? it is all withing PHP code

```
echo '

var myWidth = 150;

$(".myTbl th:nth-child(1)").truncate({
        width: myWidth ,
        after: "&hellip;",
        center: false,
        addtitle: true
}); ';
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Do you have an error?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, so the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps the plugin expects a string and in the second snippet you're supplying it a number.

Comment: Maybe the plugin is expecting a string?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker If I replace  myWidth with "150" it works fine... It does not produce any errors, but the browsers keeps on spinning like it's waiting for something. It goes away as soon as I hard-code a numeric value. Weird, hah?

Comment: @Benjam How do I convert my value into a string?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the plugin is expecting a string literal.

serverside:

```
echo '

    $(".myTbl th:nth-child(1)").truncate({
        width: "150" ,
        after: "&hellip;",
        center: false,
        addtitle: true
    }); 
';
```

js side:

```
echo '

    var myWidth = "150";

    $(".myTbl th:nth-child(1)").truncate({
        width: myWidth ,
        after: "&hellip;",
        center: false,
        addtitle: true
    }); 
';
```

Comment: That was my thought too. You could also just quote your value when setting it to myWidth. `var myWidth = "150";`

Comment: @idrumgood I think your solution is better. @mrtsherman Your code will cause a parse error in PHP unless I'm reading incorrectly. The width line should read `width: myWidth.toString(),`.